# Ошибка в работе функции frac()

Tags: pascalabc.net

```
var x,y:real;
begin
    x:=123.456;
    y:=frac(x);
    write(y);
end.
```

В результате выводит 0.456000000000003.

Comment: А вопрос в чём? Пока что я вижу только суждение про некорректную работу стандартной функции, которое никак не учитывает специфику хранения вещественных чисел.

Comment: http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=374

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нет никакой ошибки. Просто сам способ хранения действительных чисел основан на сумме дробей вида 1/2<sup>n</sup>, ну, а ваше 0.456 - это не 0.5, его красиво не разложишь :)

Выводите с меньшим количеством знаков, и все будет красиво :)